# Cloud Run Docker container - How to access DB on VM?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a python application running in a docker container in Google Cloud Run.
I have a VM instance which hosts a MongoDB instance. I need my python application, which is running in a docker container to access the database in the VM.

So far, it only runs in a Connection refused error. I "probably" understand that this is because it is not able to recognize the outside IP address. How do I make the application in the docker container access the outside world?

**Edit**: The problem was not with container not being able to access the outside world. The problem was that the "internal IP address" was not reachable. The solution, as suggested by @guillaumeblaquiere was to create a Serverless VPC Connector.

Comment: Provide detail on how you configured Cloud Run and the code that connects to Cloud SQL. Hint: your code does not directly connect to Cloud SQL. Cloud Run provides the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy and you connect to a Unix socket. The Cloud Run documentation has details and examples.

Comment: Use a serverless VPC connector and access to your VPC through it. however, without more details, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: thank you @guillaumeblaquiere, this is exactly what was required - serverless VPC connector. From the documentation it looks like this should work fine. I will try it out and post my observations.

Comment: @funkycoder Good job on finding the solution to your own question. Could you post your solution as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Posting [@guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) comment for visibility:

> Use a serverless VPC connector and access to your VPC through it.

As stated in the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73282336/revisions):

> The problem was not with container not being able to access the outside world. The problem was that the "internal IP address" was not reachable.

See also:

- [Connect to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)
- [Configure private access to MongoDB Atlas with Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/serverless-vpc-access-private-mongodb-atlas)